# fixing the navbar/menu at the top when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help in fxing the navigation bar at the top of the page whenever i am scrolling. Its a requirement for my project and I'm having difficulties in doing this. Please help me!

Below is the code for the navbar/menu that I wanted to fix at the top of the page

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 50) {
      document.getElementById('navbar_top').classList.add('fixed-top');
      // add padding top to show content behind navbar
      navbar_height = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
      document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('navbar_top').classList.remove('fixed-top');
      // remove padding top from body
      document.body.style.paddingTop = '0';
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar_top {
  position: fixed;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="hdn-head">
    <h2>Hello, Sign in</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hdn-content">
    <h3>Digital Content & Devices</h3>
    <ul>
      <div>
        <li>Amazon Music</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Kindle E-Readers & Books</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Appstore for Android</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hdn-content">
    <h3>Shop By Department</h3>
    <ul>
      <div>
        <li>Electronics</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Computers</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Smart Homes</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Arts & Crafts</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hdn-content">
    <h3>Programs & Features</h3>
    <ul>
      <div>
        <li>Gift Cards & Mobile Recharges</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Flight Tickets</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <li>Clearance Store</li><i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
<div class="triangle"><i class="fa-solid fa-triangle"></i></div>
<div class="hdn-sign">
  <div class="hdn-table">
    <div>
      <h3>Your Lists</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Create a List</li>
        <li>Find a List & Registry</li>
        <li>Amazon Smile Charity Lists</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="hdn-line"></div>
    <div>
      <h3>Your Account</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Account</li>
        <li>Orders</li>
        <li>Recommendations</li>
        <li>Browsing History</li>
        <li>Watchlist</li>
        <li>Video Purchases</li>
        <li>Kindle Unlimited</li>
        <li>Content & Devices</li>
        <li>Subscribe & Save Items</li>
        <li>Membership</li>
        <li>Music Library</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="black"></div>


<header id="navbar_top">
  <section class="navbar">
    <div class="first">
      <div class="flex logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        <div class="map flex">
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i>
          <div>
            <span>Deliver to</span>
            <span>Philippines</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex input">
        <div>
          <span>All</span>
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="flex right">
        <div class="flex lang">
          <img src="images/usflag.jpg" alt="">
          <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="sign">
          <span>Hello, Sign in</span>
          <div class="flex ac">
            <span>Accounts & Lists</span>
            <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sign">
          <span>Returns</span>
          <span>& Orders</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex cart">
          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          <span class="ca">Cart</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <div class="second-1">
        <div>
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          <span>All</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second-2">
        <ul>
          <li>Today's Deal</li>
          <li>Customer Service</li>
          <li>Registry</li>
          <li>Gift Cards</li>
          <li>Sell</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="second-3">
        <span>Shop Valentine's Day</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
```

Can you please help me create a code for this? Its an Amazon Clone Project that I need to finish for my job. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Your JS seems to be adding "fixed-top" to the classlist of your nav/header element while your CSS is applying its style to the navbar_top class.
I tried replacing this in a JS Fiddle and I had your desired behaviour.

```
/* edit class selector:
.navbar_top{ */
.fixed-top {
/* and leave the rest unchanged: */
position: fixed;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

There are still some improvements you could make.
Such as the use of correct html tags (e.g. `<nav>`, see https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ )
Or a way of handling opacity between your navbar and body content.

I'm sure you can find all your answers easily though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: sticky` on your navbar/ menu. This eliminates the need for any JS.

```css
body {
  height: 900vh;
  background: linear-gradient(gold, violet)
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  background: gainsboro;
}
```

```html
<header>I'm going to stick to the top as the page gets scrolled</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the class selector in CSS, but `navbar_top` is an ID. change to the id selector:

```
#navbar_top {
  position: fixed;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```